# Error in just_audio PlatformException(-1004, Could not connect to the server., null, null). This problem only occurs in IOS release mode

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, just-audio

=> I am using just_audio for playing network audio in my application, and For Android, it's working fine but in IOS release mode errors come like **PlatformException(-1004, Could not connect to the server., null, null)**

=> Passing token with network url

**AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(mediaItem.extras!['url'] as String),
tag: mediaItem, headers: {"Cookie": "token=$token"});**

Comment: related? https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/594